# Find a counter-example for inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, polynomials

Let $C>1$ be a constant. I have to find polynomial $p(t)=a_0+a_1 t+\dots +a_n t^n$ such that:

$$|a_0|+|a_1|+\dots + |a_n| \le C \sup_{t\in[0,1]} |p(t)|$$ 
doesn't hold.

Any tip?

Comment: Do you just need one example or are you trying to find all the possible $p(t)$'s? 
As example you could just take $p(t)=1$.

Comment: I just need one $p(t)$ for which this inequality DOESN'T hold. Sadly, for $p(t)=1$ it does hold...

Comment: If $C\lt2$, then you can let $p(t)=1-t$.

Comment: but $C$ is an unknown constant and we only know that it is greater than $1$. I need a general counter-example without restricting $C$

Comment: without an upper bound on $C$, I'm not sure this works.  You can always choose $C$ as $\frac{(n+1) \max(a_n)}{\sup |p(t)|}$ ($\sup$ taken on the interval), in which case the equality will always hold.  Unless the $\sup$ is zero, in which case the polynomial is the zero polynomial (and this satisfies the inequality), or if we're allowed to create an infinite sequence of $a_n$, in which case its no longer a polynomial.  (first impressions on the question, i may be missing something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$\begin{align}
p(t)&=1-t+t^2-t^3+\cdots+t^{2N-2}-t^{2N-1}\\
&=(1-t)(1+t^2+t^4+\cdots+t^{2N-2})\\
&=(1-t){1-t^{2N}\over1-t^2}\\
&={1-t^{2N}\over1+t}
\end{align}$$

Clearly $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|p(t)|\le1$ and $|a_0|+|a_1|+\cdots=1+1+\cdots=2N$.  So whatever $C$ is, take $N$ so that $C\lt2N$.